# Rails 4: properly using content_for/rendering partials

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, rendering

I have never used `content_for` before but it seems quite helpful.

I'm probably making this more difficult then it has to be, but the goal is:

**Have a custom header on a products#index page.**

Currently, I have that header set up as a partial (`_header.html.erb`) in the products folder. I was calling

`<%= render "header" %>` on the products `index` page, but there was a slight margin above the header: so upon using Inspect Element there seemed to be a margin linked within the body of the `products.css.scss` page: there in fact is a `margin-top` value of 40px in products.css.scss, but why on earth is that being transferred over to the header partial in `app/views/products/` ?

I'm trying to understand this the clean way so I don't have a whole disgusting whirlwind of CSS. It seems using `content_for` approach here is viable (but maybe overcomplicated for something like this?), but I feel since my `_header.html.erb` file has the following it should be ok

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "header" %>
  <div id="transparent-box">
    <div class="logo-red"></div>
    <div class="banner-items">
      <%= link_to 'About', '#', :class => 'banner-item' %>
      <%= link_to 'Shop', '/products', :class => 'banner-item' %>
      <%= link_to 'Contact', '#', :class => 'banner-item' %>
      <%= link_to 'Cart', '/products/current', :class => 'banner-item' %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`content_for :____` basically stores a set of HTML which can be called in another part of the layout (an elaborate variable), as [described in the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for):

> Calling #content_for stores a block of markup in an identifier for
>   later use. In order to access this stored content in other templates,
>   helper modules or the layout, you would pass the identifier as an
>   argument to content_for

In my experience, `content_for` is indifferent from a code perspective - it only stores what you tell it to. Therefore your CSS issue is not really a problem from the use of `content_for`, but a problem with how you're calling your `header` file I think

---

**Fix**

From your description, I think your calling of `render partial: "header"` could be interfering with the CSS you have throughout your document. Remember, just because you're calling a partial doesn't mean it has no CSS styling -- your classes will still have styling, which are likely defined in your CSS somewhere

Why not try this:

```
#app/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= content_for :header %>

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
include ApplicationHelper

#Content_For
def view_context
    super.tap do |view|
        (@_content_for || {}).each do |name,content|
            view.content_for name, content
        end
    end
end

def content_for(name, content) # no blocks allowed yet
    @_content_for ||= {}
    if @_content_for[name].respond_to?(:<<)
        @_content_for[name] << content
    else
        @_content_for[name] = content
    end
end

def content_for?(name)
    @_content_for[name].present?
end

#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
def index
    content_for :header, render partial: "products/header" #-> not sure if syntax is right
end
```

This will load the `header` `content_for` block if there is content inside

Comment: Hi Rich, I definitely appreciate the very detailed answer, but I just ended up changing the html classes/ids (I swear I tried it last night without success) for the `header` partial and all seemed OK. Probably not the most concise approach but it will do for now.